# Do multiple registrations of IFilterProvider still work in MVC5?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5, unity-container, asp.net-mvc-filters

I am sure that this code used to work. I have a UnityFilterProvider and a UnityGlobalFilterProvider both registered in my Unity config.

I would have expected it to pick up both IFilterProviders, but if they are both registered it will only pick up the GlobalFilterProvider. If the only one registered is the basic UnityFilterProvider then that works fine.

But I cannot get them both working together.

Am I doing something wrong? Did this used to work, but not in MVC5? Did this never work and should I do something different?

UnityFilterProvider.cs

```cs
namespace Website.Infrastructure
{
    public class UnityFilterProvider : FilterAttributeFilterProvider
    {
        private IUnityContainer container;

        public UnityFilterProvider(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            this.container = container;
        }

        public override IEnumerable<Filter> GetFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
        {
            var filters = base.GetFilters(controllerContext, actionDescriptor);

            foreach (var filter in filters)
            {
                container.BuildUp(filter.Instance.GetType(), filter.Instance);
            }

            return filters;
        }
    }
}
```

UnityGlobalFilterProvider.cs

```cs
namespace Website.Infrastructure
{
    public class UnityGlobalFilterProvider : IFilterProvider
    { 
        private readonly IUnityContainer container;
        private readonly IGlobalFilterRegistrationList filterList;

        public UnityGlobalFilterProvider(IUnityContainer container, IGlobalFilterRegistrationList filterList)
        {
            this.container = container;
            this.filterList = filterList;
        }

        public IEnumerable<Filter> GetFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
        {
            var filters = new List<Filter>();
            if (filterList == null || filterList.Count == 0)
                return filters;

            foreach (GlobalFilterRegistration registration in filterList)
            {
                var actionFilter = container.Resolve(registration.Type);
                var filter = new Filter(actionFilter, FilterScope.Global, registration.Order);
                filters.Add(filter);
            }

            return filters;
        }
    }

    public class GlobalFilterRegistration
    {
        public GlobalFilterRegistration(Type type, int? order)
        {
            this.Type = type;
            this.Order = order;
        }

        public Type Type { get; set; }
        public int? Order { get; set; }
    }

    public class GlobalFilterRegistrationList : List<GlobalFilterRegistration>, IGlobalFilterRegistrationList
    {
    }

    public interface IGlobalFilterRegistrationList
    {
        int Count { get; }
        List<GlobalFilterRegistration>.Enumerator GetEnumerator();
        void Add(GlobalFilterRegistration item);
    }
}
```

UnityConfig (snip)

```
container.RegisterType<IFilterProvider, UnityFilterProvider>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<IFilterProvider, UnityGlobalFilterProvider>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<IGlobalFilterRegistrationList, GlobalFilterRegistrationList>(
    new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

Anyone got any ideas?

Adding names to the provider registrations solved the problem

```
container.RegisterType<IFilterProvider, UnityFilterProvider>("UnityFilterProvider", new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<IFilterProvider, UnityGlobalFilterProvider>("UnityGlobalFilterProvider", new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

Comment: How you register the filters?

Comment: I just tried with your code, and both Global and standard Action filters works ok. Your issue might be related to the way you register the action filters.

Comment: I am currently not registering the action filters. Didn't think I needed to. How are you registering them?

Comment: updated the answer as below.

Comment: Has the below answer fixed your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding names to the Filter registrations solved the problem.

```
    container.RegisterType<IFilterProvider, UnityFilterProvider>("UnityFilterProvider", new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
    container.RegisterType<IFilterProvider, UnityGlobalFilterProvider>("UnityGlobalFilterProvider", new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

Cheers Mike

Comment: I usually use `typeof(TypeToRegister).Name`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is due to the way the filters being registered. The works for me.

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<IFilterProvider, UnityFilterProvider>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<IFilterProvider, UnityGlobalFilterProvider>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<IGlobalFilterRegistrationList, GlobalFilterRegistrationList>(
            new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

        container.RegisterType<I, C>();
        container.RegisterType<IActionFilter, SomeActionFilterAttribute>();

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);

        GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new SomeGlobalFilterAttribute());

        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

    }
}

public interface I
{ }

public class C : I
{ }


public class SomeGlobalFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    [Dependency]
    public I C { get; set; }
    public SomeGlobalFilterAttribute()
    {

    }
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var c = C;
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}

public class SomeActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    [Dependency]
    public I C { get; set; }
    public SomeActionFilterAttribute()
    {

    }
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var c = C;
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: Registering the ActionFilters did nothing for me. However what did work was giving each of the FilterPRoviders a name in the registration. I seem to remember that if you want to register the same Interface against multiple objects in Unity then you must give each one a unique name. Did that and it all works, without registering the filters in Unity.